# Seven circles inscribed in a circle problem

Tags: geometry, triangles, circles

[This is the detail given, Diameter of inner circle is 50. I need to find out middle circle and outer circle radius](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ciJHl.png)

The answer is given at the end of the book but I want to learn how to do the calculation. I know that outer circle is 126,6 and smaller middle cirles are 38.3 .

I have tried solving it this way: Having the equilateral triangle, the height of it is 43.3. Doubling that is 86,6. Equilateral height line doubled in dark red.

[Having the equilateral triangle, the height of it is 43.3. Doubling that is 86,6. Equilateral height line doubled in dark red.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M6A9j.png) I have been stuck at this for hours, so I need tips what to do next.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is enough to consider the triangle $\triangle {OAB}$ involving the inner circle of radius $50$ and two of the searched seven circles of unknown radius $r$. Since  angle $\angle{BOC}=\dfrac{\pi}{7}$ we have the equation $$\frac{r}{50+r}=\sin\left(\dfrac{\pi}{7}\right)=0.433883739$$ so $r=38.32108076$. From which the radius of the outer circle is equal to $126.64216153$

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Let $O$ be inner circle center, and $A$ and $B$ be two adjacent middle circles centers. Then we know $\angle AOB = 2\pi/7$ as there are $7$ middle circles around and all their adjacent center's angles on $O$ will be same. We know inner circle's radius is $50$, let r be the middle circle's radius. Then the triangle given in here [image] will have sides $50+r, 50+r$ and $2r$ (not an equilateral triangle as in your question) We can draw the angle bisector of $\angle AOB$, and applying $\sin(\pi/7) = \frac{r}{50+r}$ in the right angled triangle which will form, we get $r=\frac{50\sin(\pi/7)}{1-\sin(\pi/7)}\approx 38.32108$. Now radius of outer circle is just $50 + 2r \approx 126.64216 $